# add_option_page capability behaving strange

Tags: user-access

I am trying to build a class to make the job off adding new settings easier. The trouble I am having is that, although I have traced the variable through all of it's stages, the string 'manage_options' doesn't seem to grant admin the right to amend and option. I keep getting "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page." when I try access the new settings page.

Here is a heavily simplified version of the class, the creation function and its action hook.

```
class optionObject{
    var $user_level = 'manage_options';

    function add_page() {

        add_options_page(menu_page_title, page_title, $this->user_level, menu_slug, array(&$this, 'do_page'));

    }
    function do_page(){
        //do stuff to display page
    }
}

function test_options(){
    $options = new optionObject();

    add_action('admin_menu', $options->add_page());
}

add_action('admin_init', 'test_options' );
```

Unedited Version [here](http://pastebin.com/gYufecdR)

Comment: for test purposed, I changed the capability to the lowest, which is 'read', I still can't access my settings page!!

Comment: Your callback to `admin_menu` is set up wrong. It should be `add_action('admin_menu', array($options, 'add_page'))`. Currently, you immediately execute the `$options->add_page()` function in the `admin_init` hook, which might be too early.

Comment: I have directly copied that in, now the add_page function isn't firing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`admin_init` is called [*after* `wp-admin/menu.php` is included](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/admin.php#L93), so [the access check has already been executed](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/menu.php#L441) and [the `admin_menu` action has fired](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/menu.php#L328) by the time you execute `test_options()`. Remove the `admin_init` hook and call `test_options()` directly, or find another way of structuring your code so that the `admin_menu` hook is set up correctly.

You might think it could work because you see the menu option when you are on other pages. This is because **the menu is drawn after the page access is checked**:

The menu is drawn in:

- [`wp-admin/menu-header.php` on line 169](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/menu-header.php#L169)

  - included in [`wp-admin/admin-header.php` on line 143](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/admin-header.php#L143)

    - included from various places, but always after [`wp-admin/admin.php` line **132**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/admin.php#L132)

      - which is after `admin_init` fires in [`wp-admin/admin.php` on line **98**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/admin.php#L98)

The access check however is done in:

- [`wp-admin/menu.php` on line 441](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/menu.php#L441)

  - which is after `admin_menu` fires in [`wp-admin/menu.php` on line 328](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/menu.php#L328)

    - which is included in [`wp-admin/admin.php` on line **93**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/admin.php#L93)

You see that adding menu items in `admin_init` is OK to be included in the drawn menu, but too late for the access check. That's your current situation, and you need to change that by adding the page in the `admin_menu` hook or earlier.

Comment: Okay, that has got the page firing after the initial code change, but still getting read permission error on access. I have put the full version on a pastebin link in the original question.

Comment: @Mild Fuzz: You should not add the page in the `admin_init` hook, but already in the `admin_menu` hook. So replace `add_action('admin_init', array($options, 'add_page'));` with a direct call to `$options->add_page()` (since you call it in `admin_menu`), and it should work.

Comment: what is odd is that the 'admin_init' get's fired on the dashboard, but not when you go to the page, but the construct is being fired on both.

Comment: @Mild Fuzz: I expanded my answer with a call tree of the drawing of the menu and the access check, so you can see that you were too late with the definition of your menu item.

Answer (score 1):

Jan is spot on with both his answer and comment on the original question..

Here's an example of the code working, in it's most basic form...

```
// Either uncomment the constructor function or the line following the creation of the object, simply showing you two working methods
class test_stuff {
    var $user_level = 'manage_options';
    // PHP4 or PHP5 constructor, you choose - uncomment function line as appropriate
    //function test_stuff() {
    //function __construct() {
    //    add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_new_page' ) );
    //}
    function add_new_page() {
        add_options_page( 'somename', 'somename', $this->user_level, 'somepagename', array( $this, 'display_page' ) );
    }
    function display_page() {
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }
}
$test_stuff = new test_stuff();
//add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $test_stuff, 'add_new_page' ) ); // Alternative to using the constructor function
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: Or to provide PHP4+5 constructors, do something like `function test_stuff() { $this->__construct(); } function __construct() { add_action(...); }`. (Now it's a bit confusing as your crucial hook is commented out)

Comment: I personally just use the PHP 5 constructor, just offered it up as an alternative.. :)

Comment: no good still, put full version in pastebin link in original question.

Comment: I tested the code i posted, it worked using both methods for me. Are you using WP 3.0.1?, and do you have any plugins enabled? What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: Your full version is still using the admin_init hook despite the advice you've been given, please re-read the answers and comments that have been provided to you.